# Downloading data from JS into JS html file

Tags: javascript, html, download

How to make script replace the code from "Code:" instead of html

I know this code does not work, but it has been modified for this post to illustrate the problem.

```html
<html>
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
<body>
     
 
<div id="informacja"></div>
 
<script>
$( "#informacja" ).load( ".html" );
</script>    
     
     
  
<div id="tytul"></div>
 
  
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('liveload', function() {
        wn.getDatasheet(
   {
    'title':'#tytul',
   },
   {
            Code: '0000000000',
        }, 'pl')
    });
</script>
  
  
<script src="#####"></script>
<script src="#####"></script> 
  
</body>
</html>
```

I need the text I type to be completed in place .load ("") when running the script. I have to put this code in 5,000 places and write what is in Code every time will take me a lot of time.